# IntelliSense autocomplete "on dot" choosing incorrect symbol

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm editing a stand-alone JavaScript file in VSCode 1.19.2. I do not have a project set up, and no `jsconfig.json` to control it.

I enter the following code into an empty editor:

`var scene = new THREE`

Intellisense starts to kick in and gives an auto-complete list.

[image]

When I press "." (expecting my code to become `THREE.`), IntelliSense takes this as a sign that it gave me the right answer, and changes my code to:

`var scene = new HTMLHRElement.`

The full string "`THREE`" wasn't even in the list, but IntelliSense seems to be using some kooky regular expression to predict what the user actually tried to type--the letters are all there in the applied symbol, but they're all split up and in different cases.

For me, this is counter-intuitive (not to mention frustrating beyond words, because I type this string a lot), but everything I've found so far is people asking *for* this feature. So, I'm looking for a work-around for me.

Is there any way to turn off "complete on dot," or maybe a similar setting to force IntelliSense autocomplete only on tab? Also feel free to correct my terminology, in case that was preventing me from finding the correct answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JavaScript and TypeScript treat `.` as accepting the current suggestion by default. You can disable this by setting:

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false
```

or, if you only want them disabled in js:

```
"[javascript]": {
  "editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false
}
```